# Passing value from winform 2 to winform for process

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two winform **FormA** and **FormB** when I click button in FormA, FormB will be launched.

FormB has some buttons each button is assigned some values, when I click any button the value assigned to that form has to be passed to formA where I need process but both Form has to be active.

The following code is attached to formA button which launches formB

```
            FormA bar = new FormA ("Login");
            bar = this;
            FormB pad = new FormB (ref bar);
            pad.ShowDialog();
            MessageBox.Show(this.getValue.ToString());
```

The problem is that I am not able to read the value clicked in FormB button untill I close formB screen. I am looking at some way to delegate the value to FormA for processing.

My FormB looks like,

```
   FormA s = null;
    string txtInput = String.Empty;

    public FormB (ref FormA form1handle)
    {
       InitializeComponent();
        s = form1handle;
    }

    public string getFormBValue {
        get { return txtInput; }
    }

 private void Dial1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //txtInput = Dial1.Text;
        s.getValue = Dial1.Text;
        MessageBox.Show(s.getValue.ToString());           
    }
```

PS: using FormB I am trying to implement a phone dialpad, which will be used to pass DTMF input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your described scenario I would make use of the [EventHandler Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler.aspx) in your `FormB` that triggers an `event` which is monitored by your `FormA`.

`FormB` (I referred to as Form2)

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEventHandler;

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var eventArgs = new MyEventArgs()
            {
                TriggeredDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Value = 5
            };

            OnMyEventHandler(eventArgs);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var eventArgs = new MyEventArgs()
            {
                TriggeredDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Value = 10
            };

            OnMyEventHandler(eventArgs);
        }

        private void OnMyEventHandler(MyEventArgs args)
        {
            var handler = MyEventHandler;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, args);
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public DateTime TriggeredDateTime { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`FormA` (I referred to as Form1)

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication
{
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Form2 form2;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            form2 = new Form2();
            form2.MyEventHandler += Form2EventHandler;

        }

        public void Form2EventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs args)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Received value: {0}", args.Value));
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            form2.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

I have omitted the design code as it is far to verbose, however, you can see from the example above that `FormB` (Form2) has two button controls and `FormA` (Form1) has a single button control.

`Form2` exposes an `EventHandler` which `Form1` subscribes to, when a `Button` in `Form2` is pressed an instance of `MyEventArgs` is created which stores the value you want to send to `Form1` (along with a DateTime value as a nicety) and the `OnMyEventHandler` delegate is raised.  `Form1` then detects the event has been raised and the `Form2EventHandler` processes the event.

The `EventHandler` delegate method will work with other controls too should you desire.  You could alter `MyEventArgs` to have as many `Properties` as you like which could be `set` via a number of `TextBox` controls on `Form2` where a `Button` control is pressed should you desire.

Comment: I am looking for some thing like this. I will test it and update  ASAP.

Comment: When I declare  public EventHandler<MyEventArgs> MyEventHandler;  I get this error.  "The type 'FormA .FormB.MyEventArgs' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEventArgs' in the generic type or method 'System.EventHandler<TEventArgs>'"

Comment: That is caused by the class `MyEventArgs` not explicitly deriving from `EventArgs`.  .NET 4 requires you to explicitly derive from `EventArgs`, .NET 4.5 (which I built my example under) does not.  I have updated my example, for `Form2` to show `MyEventArgs` deriving from `EventArgs`.

Comment: I should have been more explicit, .NET 4 and earlier requires you to explicitly derive from `EventArgs`.  The update I made earlier will still work under .NET 3.5.

Comment: I have modified my code accordingly, Still I am getting the same error. **The type 'FormA .FormB.MyEventArgs' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEventArgs' in the generic type or method 'System.EventHandler<TEventArgs>**

Comment: Glad you got it resolved.  What was the issue, for my piece of mind and in case others encounter something similar?

Comment: I made a horrible mistake on pasting ur "MyEventArgs" class in my code.  While copying was correct but I pasted inside FormB. I guess that triggered the problem. I realized and re-worked on my code and built again. That resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden textbox to Form B and add a method `SetChildFromValueToParent` to Form A which gets invoked when value of the hidden textbox in the Form B is changed. Basically for the button client event in the Form B you have to set the button value to hidden textbox in the Form B.

Add the following logic to your `A` button click which opens the `B`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    B childForm = new B();

    //Find the textbox control in the child form
    Control[] controls = childForm.Controls.Find("textBox", true);

    if (null != controls[0])
    {
        //Bind the method in the parent form to child form text control's TextChanged event
        controls[0].TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(SetChildFromValueToParent);
    }

    childForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Add the following method to your `From A`

```
  private void SetChildFromValueToParent(object obj, EventArgs args)
        {
             //Read the child form's hidden control value and set it to parent form
             B from2 = new B();
             string value =  ((TextBox)form2.Controls["textBox1"]).Text;            
        }
```

Comment: I tried to update the code as per ur suggestion. But the moment I click the button in FormA  to launch FormB the entire application crashes.

Comment: Did you add a hidden textbox to Form B with the name textbox. This line needs that Control[] controls = childForm.Controls.Find("textBox", true);

Comment: Yes I did, ToolStripTextBox textbox = new ToolStripTextBox(). I tried with TextBox as well did not work.

Comment: You have to add a textbox to Form B and set the visible to False and give the name of that textbox in Controls.Find("textBox", true); and ((TextBox)form2.Controls["textBox1"]).Text;

Answer (score 0):

You can create some public properties in your **FormB** and set them within that form. Then use these properties in **FormA** to get the data. Here is the example (assuming you have "Close" button and textbox in FormB):

```
public partial class FormB : Form
{
   public string PhoneNumber { get; private set; }

   private void buttonClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       this.PhoneNumber = textBoxPhone.Text;
       this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
       this.Close();
   }
}
```

Then in your **FormA**:

```
FormB pad = new FormB();
var phoneFromFormB = String.Empty;
if (pad.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    phoneFromFormB = pad.PhoneNumber;            
}
```

**Update**

If you need both forms to be active, just set properties in **FormB** without closing it. After properties are set, they can be accessed from **FormA**. Also to make them both active you will need to use `Show()` method instead of `ShowDialog()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of FormB being a form, why not create FormB as a [**UserControl**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx) which can be added to FormA - drag from Toolbox once compiled in the form designer.

Then you can access the properties/methods of FormA directly from your UserControl, either through the ParentForm property or by a reference passed to it (concrete class or interface). Short [**tutorial**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jayendra/how-to-create-usercontrol-in-windows-form-application/). This means both FormA and the Dialpad can be active at the same time as ShowDialog is modal.

No need to use the ref keyword either as Forms are reference types. Note: I would implement an interface in FormA and use that as the type rather than FormA directly.

```
public FormB : UserControl
{

    FormA s = null;
    string txtInput = String.Empty;

    public FormB (FormA form1handle)
    {
       InitializeComponent();
        s = form1handle;
    }

    public FormB()
    {

    }

    public FormA Parent 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            if(s == null)
               s = (FormA)ParentForm; 
             return s; 
         } 
     }

    public string getFormBValue {
        get { return txtInput; }
    }

 private void Dial1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //txtInput = Dial1.Text;
        Parent.getValue = Dial1.Text;
        MessageBox.Show(Parent.getValue.ToString());           
    }
  }
```